# Adding Edit frames while following Helix Guidelines

Tags: experience-editor, helix

I want to create a TDS package to include the edit frames related to my components and I want to make sure that I am following the helix guidelines.

The edit frames are added in the core database but I am not sure if this should be added as a part of the feature or the project layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fixed definition in Helix Guideline to add anything to a project, feature, or foundation layer, Helix's purpose is to secure implementations in a future-proof way by architecting them as maintainable and extensible business-centric modules.

Most of the time when we are developing anything that is specific to a feature only it will part of the feature layer and when something is common for multiple features we add them into the foundation layer. In your case, if the Edit frame related changes you did in the core database is specific to your feature only then I will suggest you create a core database-specific TDS project in your feature layer, and if these edit frame related changes are common for multiple features then add it in the foundation layer.

Please always keep in mind that Sitecore Helix is a set of principles that are open to interpretation, not step-by-step directions.